# DB2 Trigger Row Locking

Tags: sql, triggers, db2

I want to create a trigger in DB2 10.1.2 (LUW running on Linux) that when a field is updated to a certain value, the number of rows in that table are counted with that value to see if it matches a count in another table and then that table is updated (e.g. rolling up task status into a job status).  Expressing it seemed pretty easy:

```
CREATE TRIGGER AUTHORED
  AFTER UPDATE OF TASK_STATUS ON TASK_TABLE
  REFERENCING NEW AS N FOR EACH ROW WHEN (TASK_STATUS = 'Completed')
    update JOB_TABLE set JOB_STATUS='Completed'
      where JOB_TABLE.ID = N.JOB_ID
        and JOB_TABLE.TOTAL_TASKS = (select count(*) from TASK_TABLE
          where TASK_TABLE.JOB_ID = N.JOB_ID
            and TASK_TABLE.TASK_STATUS = 'Completed')
```

Unfortunately, it seems that the context of the trigger and the body of the trigger are not in the same unit of work and a deadlock occurs when you count the row locked from the triggered update itself.  Here's the output of "db2pd -wlocks" after I do a triggered update:

```
Locks being waited on :
AppHandl [nod-index] TranHdl    Lockname                   Type       Mode Conv Sts CoorEDU    AppName  AuthID   AppID
44248    [000-44248] 111        0200040E070000000000000052 RowLock    ..X       G   1385       perl     KJPIRES  10.0.15.139.38727.140201011731
14937    [000-14937] 15         0200040E070000000000000052 RowLock    .NS       W   1238       perl     KJPIRES  10.0.15.139.55287.140211231609
```

I tried to use "with UR" for the internal count, but that is explicitly ignored when I create the trigger ("SQL20159W  The isolation clause is ignored because of the statement context.  SQLSTATE=01652").

I also tried to use a BEFORE and a INSTEAD OF, but was having problems.

This seems like it would be something common to do.  How is it normally handled?

Comment: Have you tried 'for each statement'?

Comment: I just tried "for each statement" and it still deadlocked.  (I'm not sure what happens if the update updates multiple rows and I do "for each statement" instead of "for each row", but it didn't work anyway.)

Comment: It is not possible for a trigger to execute in a separate UOW, as you say, because the trigger body is actually compiled into the plan of the `UPDATE` statement that causes that trigger to run. How do you determine that there is a deadlock?

Comment: Is this DB2 for LUW, i, or z/OS?

Comment: What volume of rows are we looking at here?  In the tables, I mean, not the unit-of-work.  Can `JOB_STATUS` be derived on-the-fly on a regular read (say, by defining a view)?  At worst, you could define a scheduled call to check on all jobs.  Perhaps a stored procedure that commits the task status first?  Would specifying `SKIP LOCKED DATA` work here?

Comment: I have an idle database and used "db2pd -wlocks" to see the waiting locks before I did an update (there were none) and while I was doing the update (which locked up).  I'll add the output of "db2pd -wlocks" above.

BTW, it's DB2 for LUW running on Linux and small volume of rows for this test.

Comment: This job-level status is being added to a large existing system which many agents (not running during this test) and I do not wish to modify the agents that are marking their tasks as 'Completed' but I would still like the roll-up of the task status to the job level.

Comment: The triggering update is modifying TASK_STATUS ON TASK_TABLE to 'Completed' which is a requirement of the trigger and the row being updated to 'Completed' is part of the select count (which I thought was clear from my original question).  If the triggered statement and the triggering statement were in the same UOW, there wouldn't be a problem here, but it is clear they are not and as such this trigger will always deadlock.  Is there is a way to alter the trigger to have the triggered statement run in the triggering statement's UOW?  Otherwise, how would you roll up the task status to the job?

Comment: `SKIP LOCKED DATA` might work on z/OS if I assume the row for the triggering update should always included in the count and is always locked (i.e. add 1 to the count returned after the row is skipped).  Since none of our agents use auto-commit, this might be a safe assumption (and even if they did, it might be safe to assume the auto-commit doesn't happen until after the triggered statement runs).  Unfortunately, this is **DB2 10.1.2 LUW** and `SKIP LOCKED DATA` is unavailable.  (Oh, how I wish it was available.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**There is nothing wrong with the trigger above.**  Unbeknownst to me, an open transaction on my JOB_TABLE was outstanding.  I tracked it down, did a rollback and the triggering update completed.

I will use `count(0)` instead of `count(*)` as a suggested optimization.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it is deadlocked. First, DB2 has a Deadlock detector, and if there are TWO connection having locks on different resources waiting for the other, DB2 will kill one of them. I do not see two connections.

Second, you are trying to update another table (JOB_TABLE), based on a value (COUNT) from the table where the trigger is defined (TASK_TABLE)

```
CREATE TRIGGER AUTHORED
 AFTER UPDATE OF TASK_STATUS ON TASK_TABLE
 REFERENCING NEW AS N
 FOR EACH ROW WHEN (TASK_STATUS = 'Completed')
  update JOB_TABLE
   set JOB_STATUS='Completed'
   where JOB_TABLE.ID = N.JOB_ID
   and JOB_TABLE.TOTAL_TASKS = (       -- Total tasks before or after the update?
    select count(*)
    from TASK_TABLE
    where TASK_TABLE.JOB_ID = N.JOB_ID
    and TASK_TABLE.TASK_STATUS = 'Completed'
   )
```

Have you run the update outside of a trigger. Does it work, isn't it?

I think the transaction is modifying a row that is not committed (update task_table), and when you issue the select in the trigger, it waits for the commit on the same table. Actually, the transaction does not know if the row being update is in 'completed' state, and you have a predicate to seek which one update: and JOB_TABLE.TOTAL_TASKS = x, but the current row could be part of this set.

Which one are you going to update? the JOB_TABLE.TOTAL_TASKS before the current update, or after the current update? Finally, I am not sure why do you have a predicate on this.

BTW, do not use count(*) but count (0)

Comment: _when you issue the select in the trigger_ -- no, it does not.

Comment: Also, why _do not use count(*) but count (0)_?

Comment: If lower optimization level, all rows will be fetched.

Comment: This is assuming LUW.

Comment: The original update is modifying TASK_STATUS ON TASK_TABLE to 'Completed' which is a requirement of the trigger.  JOB_TABLE.TOTAL_TASKS never gets modified: it is only use to see if the total number of 'Completed' tasks matches that number.  Also, I changed my count(*) to count(0) to no effect.